# First time Using Google Maps Java API - doesn't show up in IE 10

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I'm just starting to use Google Maps API and have run into problems with API. I am using code from Good Maps example and it works with Chrome and Firefox but nothing shows up in IE 10. 
I've searched topics without help. I have added https://maps.google.com to safe site in IE, tried the v=3.28 trick, also tried meta tags for backwards compatibility, without any success.

Following is my html:

```
      <!DOCTYPE html>
      <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

      <head>
            <title></title>
      </head>
      <body>

      <div id="map" style="width:100%;height:1200px;"></div>

      <script>        
              function initMap() {
              var myLatLng = { lat: 32.681390, lng: -97.108682 };
          var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
            center: myLatLng,
            zoom: 14
        });

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: myLatLng,
            map: map,
        });

        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
        var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);            
         }        
         </script>
         <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MyKey&callback=initMap">
         </script>
         </body>
         </html>
```

The above markup doesn't show any map in IE 10. I'm unable to move forward. I'm just starting out with this and wanted to use it in an updatepanel in asp.net 4.5. But at the moment, simple html isn't working for me.

Any suggestions?
Thank you.

Comment: have you enabled activeX?

Comment: Yes, I've enabled activeX and added https://maps.google.com to safe sites. Works fine with Chrome and FireFox but won't show anything in IE.

Comment: The posted code works for me in IE11 (I don't have IE10 available).  According to the [browser support page](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/browsersupport)  IE10 is supported (as long as you aren't using compatibility mode).

Comment: google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'Load', initMap(), initialize);
Added above line to code but still no help. Still works in Chrome and Firefox but not in IE.

Comment: @geocodezip .... I am not using compatibility mode for IE 10.

Comment: Any errors in the javascript console in IE?

Comment: @geocodezip .... Just checked .. no errors in javascript console for IE.

Comment: Hi, Something to add! The Google Map isn't working on my computer. Since I was testing out on my machine I never checked from a different computer. I've uploaded my test code to my site and browsed to it from another computer which has IE 11 installed, and the map works with all markers etc. Now I'm confused. Y not on my machine?

Comment: Wanted to add that I'm working on Windows Server 2012 R2 and using Visual Studio 2012 Professional for development. I have IE-10 browser. Both O/s and VS  have the latest updates etc.